# urllib.request.urlopen is giving me errors everytime Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

**Here is my code, very simple.**

```
import urllib.request
x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com/')
print(x.read())
```

**and it is giving me this error:**

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/myName/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2017.1/scratches/scratch_3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1400, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/MattAltro/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2017.1/scratches/scratch_3.py", line 3, in <module>
    x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com/')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>
```

Process finished with exit code 1

**Please help!!**

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a security problem with `SSL`.
It works for me.

- Does it produce the same error all the times?
- Have you the lock when you go to `https://www.google.com/` in your browser? If not, this is not a python problem, but a connection problem.
- In some cases, you want to disable security checks with additional arguments `verify=False`.

Comment: yes it does.

how do i check the lock in my browser? im on a mac could that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are on OS X and Python 3.6. Python 3.6 needs a post-install step to make SSL working. There are two options evidently:

- install the certifi package
- run the /Applications/Python 3.6/Install Certificates.command

I had my python installed through Homebrew, so I didn't have the .command file, and this tried with just the certifi package. The package would install fine, but SSL still wouldn't work. I ended up downloading Python 3.6 ([from python.org](https://www.python.org/)) and running the Install Certificates.command. It worked fine from there.